# JSON / Serialize Multi Dimension Array to PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a few, dynamically generated, input field standing like:

```
<input name="title[1][name]" ... />
<input name="title[2][name]" ... />
```

If I try to serialize and post this data (via axios) directly it works just fine, however, if I try to put it inside an object it serializes in a different way and I can't not longer retrieve the data in PHP.

**This works**

```
var data = $('[name^="title"]').serialize()
axios.post(url, data)
```

Then

```
foreach($title as $t){
   print $t['name];
}
```

But the following, when trying to place it aside other data, **does not**

```
var data = {
    something: '',
    titles: $('[name^="title"]').serialize()
};
```

It seems to handle the serialize in a different way and I can't no longer properly parse it in PHP. I've tried with serializeArray(), using some additional mapping function, but it loses the multidimensional behavior.

Comment: You have assigned the value to a new object key "titles"

Comment: Yes, but trying to do foreach($some['titles'] as $title...) do not works

Comment: var_dump($_POST) and see what you get